# Quand vs. Lorsque?

Tags: choix-de-mot, indications-de-temps, conjonctions

I have read [this article](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/quand-vs-lorsque.htm) on about.com and am aware of the differences in usage and meaning between *quand* and *lorsque*. However, in the first type of usage, which in the article is termed *temporal correlation*, it is said that the two words are essentially interchangeable.

Example of the sort of usage I mean:

> Je marchais quand tu m'as téléphoné.
>     Je marchais lorsque tu m'as téléphoné.

But it has been my experience that two things are never truly identical. There must be some nuance of difference — could someone expand on this?

Comment: J'ai su que je suis un peu tard pour cette question, mais, tu a demandé un bon question!  Je pensais toujours que << lorsque >> est utilisé dans la contexte où il n'y a pas un question tandis que << quand >> qui est utilisé dans la context où il y a un question.  Pourtant, à cause de ta question, j'ai découvert que j'ai tort :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Quand* et *lorsque* sont toujours interchangeables pour exprimer la simultanéité de deux actions.

> Je dormais déjà quand/lorsqu' il m'a téléphoné.
>   Je viendrai quand/lorsque il sera l'heure.

Certains linguistes ont effectivement dit que *lorsque* serait plus littéraire.  Or une [étude de corpus récente](http://www.coelang.tufs.ac.jp/common/pdf/research_paper12/167_research_paper12.pdf) (2006) assez large a été faite et il en résulte que *quand* est significativement plus fréquent dans les corpus littéraires et *lorsque* dans les corpus juridiques institutionnels et scientifiques. L'emploi de *lorsque* est plus formel mais il n'est absolument pas littéraire. 
*Lorsque* est apparu relativement récemment (XV<sup>e</sup> siècle et a toujours été d'un emploi moins courant que *quand*.

À l'oral bien sûr *quand* est beaucoup plus courant que *lorsque*. Et une autre idée reçue qu'élimine cette étude est qu'il est faux de dire qu'on évite de juxtaposer *que* et *quand* pour des raisons d'euphonie.

> sur 10.000.000 mots, nous disposons de 224 suites *que lorsque* et de 294 suites *que quand*. Si l’on regarde dans le détail, on remarque qu’il y a 200 *que quand* rien que dans la tranche d’oral. (p.176)

Comment: Très intéressant... mais ne devrait-on pas faire attention en faisant de telles analyses de ne pas mettre tous les parleurs/auteurs dans la même catégorie ?  Certains propos seront plus formels que d'autres, et certains interlocuteurs seront plus "corrects" (par exemple en se souciant d'euphonie) que d'autres...

Comment: @mikerodent J'ai lu l'article en entier et son auteur en tient compte. L'informatique aide beaucoup pour analyser les corpus!

Answer (score 1):

It's a question of *register* of language.  You know how you can talk about "tone" of someone's writing or speech?  "Register" distinguishes between things like "formal" and "informal" use of language, but also dichotomies like "literary" or "demotic".  "Lorsque" is used by lawyers when they want to frighten people, and by novelists when they are writing quite ponderous literary stuff.

I doubt whether the singer Renaud has ever used "lorsque" in any of the lyrics of his songs.  On the other hand, Serge Gainsbourg may well have done so, possibly with a heavy use of irony.

In speech I would *always* use "quand".  If you take to writing purple prose in French, or parodying it, you might want to consider "lorsque".

Comment: So this is a strong indictment against the use of *lorsque.* I will wait for more feedback before taking this as canon.

Comment: Of course... I'm doing this out of interest.  I've been studying French for 40 years and will be very interested to read what others may say on this topic...

Comment: And you just found French.SE? Happy day for you....gold mine for French language dicussion.

Comment: *Lorsque* in Renaud's lyrics "Lorsqu'en septembre on assassine" (hexagone) ; "se couvre de neige **lorsque** tu la gigotes" (La Mere A Titi) ; "les bourgeois dorment comme des cons... **lorsque** soudain survient le drame" (Aventures De Gerard Lambert) ; "Mon ciel si bleu est devenu orage **lorsque** les bombes ont rasé mon village" (Manhattan-kaboul) ; "Femme je t’aime parce que **lorsque** le sport devient la guerre" (Miss Maggie) etc...

Comment: @Laure... merci !  Peut-on peut-être dire que "lorsque" est un mot plus narratif ?

Comment: @mikerodent Que veux-tu dire pas « narratif » ?

Comment: je veux dire plus commun dans un contexte narratif... c'est une hypothèse, rien de plus... et Renaud est peut-être conscient de s'inscrire dans une longue tradition française de chanteurs de ballades narratives...

Answer (score 1):

Ma théorie et utilisation de ces deux mots (peut être une révélation, ce soir!) ??? J'utilise "lorsque" pour évoquer un moment plus ou moins précis dans le temps, mais "quand" pour parler en général.

Exemples:

Lorsque j'arrivai au bureau, ma secrétaire avait déjà quitté. Pour de bon!
Quand je pense à elle, je suis plein de regrets...

Fais-je fausse route avec ça, les copains? J'aime croire que non! ;-)