# "Lorsque cette fille voulait un crayon elle a obtenu un petit copain". Is "quand" better fitting for this question?

Tags: sens, traduction, vocabulaire, usage, expressions-idiomatiques

J'ai lu que les deux conjonctions "lorsque" et "quand" peuvent être utilisées de manière interchangeables. Surtout dans des phrases comme :

> Lorsque cette fille a voulu un crayon elle a obtenu un petit copain.

Ma question est :

Laquelle est préférée ?

Comment: La phrase du titre est erronée : les deux verbes devraient être à l'imparfait. Celle du corps de la question est correcte avec le passé composé dans les deux propositions. Voir [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/11420/358) pour la différence entre *lorsque* et *quand* qui ont le même sens mais qui ne sont pas toujours considérés comme « interchangeables ». Compte tenu du fait que ta phrase est familière (*cf* "petit copain") personnellement j'emploierais *quand*.

Comment: @Brian quelle serait la phrase d'origine ? J'ai l'intuition qu'on ne veut pas exprimer la temporalité mais le contraste ou l'ironie du sort ici. Auquel cas "lorsque" n'est certainement pas approprié et "quand" guère plus.